# Facebook enhanced Auth Dialog Button Types

Tags: facebook, facebook-authentication

Using the Facebook enhanced auth dialog, the dialog itself shows a blue button to confirm the app at the user side. The text of this button could be:

- Add to Facebook
- Log in with Facebook
- Go to App
- Play Game

Is there any way to choose the displayed? For example I would like to use Log in with, but I always get Go to App.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you have to configure your application correctly per the blog article you got that info from ;)

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/03/02/enhanced-auth-dialog-and-updates-to-permissions/

> **New button text**
>
> In the enhanced auth dialog, the button text will be one of four
> cases: "Add to Facebook", "Log in with Facebook", “Go to App”, or
> "Play Game". Each of these were extensively tested and showed that
> more specific calls to action help users better understand the auth
> process. As the first point of contact for an app, it’s important for
> the auth dialog to exhibit a great user experience.
>
> See our Open Graph documentation to learn more about permissions and
> configuring the enhanced auth dialog.

And most importantly a quote from Lu's, the blog author, response to that same question from Sven Gali (oh svengali!):

> the four cases are context-sensitive and currently, there is no
> control for you to pick a particular button text. We show different
> button text in different situations, as we've found that users are
> more likely to install your application if the call-to-action text
> aligns with their expectations. Thus, the logic currently is something
> like*:
>
> - if the user has already installed the app and you are requesting additional permissions that includes "publish_actions", we use "Add to
>   Facebook"
> - if you're a game app, we use "Play Game"
> - if your auth dialog is shown in display=popup (e.g. after user clicks a "Log In with Facebook" fb:login button), we use "Log In with
>   Facebook"
> - in other situations, we use "Go to App"
>
> *Obligatory Disclaimer: We may adjust the logic tree in the future without notice, as we're constantly testing variations to improve the
> user-auth experience. But hopefully this is helpful so you can at
> least understand how it is currently functioning under the hood :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that Facebook appear to be adding more variants to this set of 4 now. I've noticed that newspaper apps generally have the text 'Read this article' as the button text.

Comment: I've seen "okay, watch video" on SocialCam app but still did not get where to change it on my app.